# How to scroll the checkboxes inside a dropdown by jquery.mobile.scrollview.js?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have implemented the Jquery.mobile.scrollview.js and i am able to scroll the dropdown,But what happens is when i click to scroll the checkboxes inside the dropdown the checkboxes gets invisible and only the text is shown.. IS there is any workaround is there... Please let me know..

IS there any example on this..... I am adding my code below .. and giving data-scroll = 'y' in my div part ...

```
<!-- Scroll View code -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        #evtCatcher
        {
        }
        #evtCatcher .ui-scrollview-view
        {
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="jsScroll/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="jsScroll/jsdefault.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="jsScroll/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="jsScroll/jquery.mobile.scrollview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="jsScroll/iscroll.js" type="text/javascript""></script>


   <script type="text/javascript">

        function fnClick() {

            alert('clicked');
        }

    </script>

  <script>
        $("[ data-role=page]").live("pageshow", function(event) {
            var $page = $(this);
            $page.find("[data-scroll]:not(.ui-scrollview-clip)").each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                // XXX: Remove this check for ui-scrolllistview once we've
                //      integrated list divider support into the main scrollview class.
                if ($this.hasClass("ui-scrolllistview"))
                    $this.scrolllistview();
                else {
                    var st = $this.data("scroll") + "";
                    var paging = st && st.search(/^[xy]p$/) != -1;
                    var dir = st && st.search(/^[xy]/) != -1 ? st.charAt(0) : null;

                    var opts = {};
                    if (dir)
                        opts.direction = dir;
                    if (paging)
                        opts.pagingEnabled = true;

                    $this.scrollview(opts);
                }
            });

            changeDelayFormElementClick();
        });

        function changeScrollMethod() {
            var val = $("#s_method").val();
            var $sv = $("#evtCatcher").scrollview("scrollTo", 0, 0);
            if (val === "scroll") {
                $sv.css("overflow", "scroll");
            }
            else {
                $sv.css("overflow", "hidden");
            }
            $sv.data("scrollview").options.scrollMethod = val;
        }

        function changeDelayFormElementClick() {
            $("#evtCatcher").data("scrollview").options.delayedClickEnabled = ($("#s_delay").val() === "yes");
        }

        var cb_hd_pd,
    cb_hd_sp,
    cb_hm_pd,
    cb_hm_sp,
    cb_hu_pd,
    cb_hu_sp;

        var hd = $.mobile.scrollview.prototype._handleDragStart;
        var hm = $.mobile.scrollview.prototype._handleDragMove;
        var hu = $.mobile.scrollview.prototype._handleDragStop;

        function getDummyEvent(o) {
            return { target: o.target, _pd: false, _sp: false, preventDefault: function() { this._pd = true; }, stopPropagation: function() { this._sp = true; } };
        }

        function updateEvent(e, cb_pd, cb_sp) {
            if (cb_pd.checked)
                e.preventDefault();
            if (cb_sp.checked)
                e.stopPropagation();
        }

        $.mobile.scrollview.prototype._handleDragStart = function(e, x, y) {
            hd.call(this, getDummyEvent(e), x, y);
            updateEvent(e, cb_hd_pd, cb_hd_sp);
        };

        $.mobile.scrollview.prototype._handleDragMove = function(e, x, y) {
            hm.call(this, getDummyEvent(e), x, y);
            updateEvent(e, cb_hm_pd, cb_hm_sp);
        };

        $.mobile.scrollview.prototype._handleDragStop = function(e) {
            hu.call(this, getDummyEvent(e));
            updateEvent(e, cb_hu_pd, cb_hu_sp);
        };

        $(function() {
            cb_hd_pd = $("#cb_hd_pd")[0];
            cb_hd_sp = $("#cb_hd_sp")[0];
            cb_hm_pd = $("#cb_hm_pd")[0];
            cb_hm_sp = $("#cb_hm_sp")[0];
            cb_hu_pd = $("#cb_hu_pd")[0];
            cb_hu_sp = $("#cb_hu_sp")[0];
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks in Advance :)